# [serverless-framework]Deploying app to a new stage tries to update old stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, staging

We have a simple serverless application that contains a dynamo DB table, a few lambdas and an API endpoint. We currently have the app deployed in the dev stage.

We are having some trouble deploying to the prod stage.

Here is the serverless.yaml file.

```
service: lookups
# app and org for use with dashboard.# serverless.com
app: lookups
org: xxxxxx

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  environment:
    DYNAMO_DB_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME: lookup_${self:provider.stage}
    S3_BUCKET: com.yyyyy.lookups.${self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:GetItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMO_DB_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME}"

functions:
  createOrUpdateLookups:
    handler: createOrUpdateLookups.createOrUpdateLookups
    description: create or update lookup entry in dynamodb
    environment:
      lookupTable: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMO_DB_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME}
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - suffix: .json
  getLookup:
    handler: getLookup.getLookup
    description: get persigned url for a lookup by location and lookup type
    environment:
      lookupTable: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMO_DB_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME}
      lookupBucket: ${self:provider.environment.S3_BUCKET}
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/lookup
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                location: true
                lookupType: true



resources:
  Resources:
    lookupTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMO_DB_LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME}
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: location
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: lookup
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: location
            KeyType: "HASH"
          - AttributeName: lookup
            KeyType: "RANGE"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

We deployed this to the dev stage using the following cli command:

`serverless deploy`

This created a stack in CloudFormtion called `lookups-dev`, a DymanoDB table DB table called `lookup-dev` and lambdas called `lookups-dev-createOrUpdateLookups` and `lookups-dev-getLookup` .

Now when try to deploy to a new stage called prod using this cli command

`serverless deploy --stage prod`

We get an error saying the table lookups-dev already exists in the stack with the stack id of the lookups-dev stack.

This is the full error:

> An error occurred: lookupTable - lookup_dev already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:aaaaabbbbbbbccccccdddddd:stack/lookups-dev/wwwwwww-wwwwwww-wwwwwwaws.

Question:
How do we deploy to a new stage when we have already deployed out app the dev stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What has happened is that you need to make sure that the name of the table changes on different stages. I see you use `${self:provider.stage}` to try and do this but all that does is use the value for stage under the provider section and because you haven't set one, it uses the default of `dev` always. I would suggest adding the following line under providers so that you have something like this:

```yaml
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```

What this means is that if you pass the stage on the CLI using --stage it will set the provider.stage to that value or to the default of dev.